# How to swipe both viewpager and recyclerview which is above the viewpager one at a time..?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, swipe, cardview

This is my layout page with recyclerview above viewpager.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sliderimage5"
                android:id="@+id/vpimghelper"

                />



            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vpimghelper"
                >


            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/points_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest how to swipe both viewpager and recyclerview one at a time.? Here both of them has independent swipes. Any suggestion to combine both their swipe so that they act as one whole swipeable view. The concept is similar to the homepage design of MakeMyTrip app. If anyone didn't understand the question, kindly could you refer the app design? Please do help to solve this... !!!

Comment: can you share us your design?

Comment: Are you suggesting a screenshot?

Comment: Yup. Anything that you are trying to implement

Comment: I have added the image below. Please do refer it.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but I think you have to do stuff in recyclerview's `OnScrollListener` and/or viewpager's `OnPageChangeListener`